# Fnordmetric basic auth

Tags: ruby, authentication

I want protect my stats. The easiest way to do that?

I'm using *fnordmetric* ruby gem  with *thin* server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by code inspection.
Added [wiki page with example](https://github.com/paulasmuth/fnordmetric/wiki/Use-rack-middleware-in-web-app)

```
middleware = [ [ Rack::Auth::Basic, 'Restricted Area',
                                 lambda { |username, password| [username, password] = ['admin', 'admin'] ] ]
FnordMetric::Web.new(use: middleware)
```